# Validating AWS Certificate in Google Domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-acm

Im following this tutorial to add HTTPS to my EC2 Elastic Beanstalk website:

https://medium.com/@jameshamann/configuring-your-elastic-beanstalk-app-for-ssl-9065ca091f49

I have modified my instance to run on a load balancer and created the certificate with DNS validation in AWS Certificate Manager. I entered my domain name, added the CNAME record to google domains as follows:

From AWS:
Name: `_XXXXXc0c9db9a6c9300e65f9XXXXXXXX.www.mydomainame.com.`

Type: `CNAME`

Value: `_XXXXX83f612f59e5b0568896XXXXXXXX.jfrzXXXXXX.acm-validations.aws.`

In Google Domains I created a CNAME record as follows:

Name: `_1084c0c9db9a6c9300e65f9ceXXXXXXX`

Type: `CNAME`

Value: `_XXXXXXXXX12f59e5b0568896XXXXXXX.jfrzfXXXXXX.acm-validations.aws.`

The certificate never gets validated, I have waited for days and it even expired. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What domain is your cert registered for?

It looks like you are saying AWS said the record should be `_XXXXXc0c9db9a6c9300e65f9XXXXXXXX.www.mydomainame.com` which means `_XXXXXc0c9db9a6c9300e65f9XXXXXXXX` needs to be added as a record under the subdomain of `www.mydomainame.com`

You may be adding the record under `mydomainname.com` and not under the `www` subdomain which is may be why it's not working.

I would suggest recreate the ACM create and creating a wildcard cert under the top level domain (e.g. `*.mydomainame.com`).

Comment: This is the right answer `*.mydomainame.com` That did the trick, it got validated. Thanks stranger!

Comment: hi team, I have added wild card too. But in aws it's still in pending validation. How long it will take for validation?

Comment: wildcard works! thanks!!